# automated deploy of war/ear build file is not working on jenkins

Tags: tomcat, ant, jenkins

Automation of WAR/EAR deployment using jenkins on tomcat is not working
my build and post build actions is as follows:

Build
Invoke Ant

Ant version : Default

target : buildall packageall testall deploy undeploy

build file : project-bare/build.xml

properties :

```
build.artifact=${BUILD_ARTIFACT}
build.tag=${BUILD_TAG}
artifact.dir=${WORKSPACE}/${ARTIFACT_DIR}
build.file.dir=${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_FILE_DIR}
url=${DB_URL}
user=${DB_USER}
server.name=${SERVER_NAME} 
server.user=${SERVER_USER}
tomcat.init=${TOMCAT_INIT} 
tomcat.dir=${TOMCAT_DIR}
```

post build actions (plug-in):

Deploy war/ear to a container

```
        WAR/EAR files : project.war
        context path  : project
        container     : tomcat7.x

                manager user name : username
                manager password  : password
                tomcat url        : http://my url:8080
```

it is showing build is successful but if i go to the server to see the latest deployed war file it is showing the old version,so that means it is not deploying it.
please help !!

Comment: My gut feeling says: Double check your parameters and if they all appear to be correct. Go through the log line by line and see if it actually deployed successfully.

Comment: You'll need to show relevant parts of catalina.out on the tomcat server.

Comment: it gives following error: ecom-rest.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
  Redeploying [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ecom_deploy/workspace/ecom-rest/build/jar/ecom-rest.war]
  Undeploying [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ecom_deploy/workspace/ecom-rest/build/jar/ecom-rest.war]
  Deploying [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ecom_deploy/workspace/ecom-rest/build/jar/ecom-rest.war]
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ecom_deploy/workspace/ecom-rest/build/jar/ecom-rest.war]